# Push\Pull docker images to Artifactory

Tags: docker, artifactory, windows-server-2016

I'm trying to push docker images to artifactory as part of a CI jenkins job.
I have an Artifactory installed with url art:8080
I installed Docker on Win2016 and built my dockerfile.

Now I stuck in how to push the output image of the dockerfile.
I tried:

```
<!-- language: lang-none -->

docker tag microsoft/windowsservercore art:8080/imageID:latest
docker push art:8080/docker-local:latest
```

but I get an error stating:

```
Get https://art:8080/v2/: dial tcp: lookup artifactory: getaddrinfow: No such host is known.
```

Where is the https getting from?
How do I push to the correct local docker repo in my artifactory?

Comment: Have you set up a reverse proxy as described here: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+a+Reverse+Proxy#ConfiguringaReverseProxy-DockerReverseProxySettings ?

Comment: I want to use Docker->Artifactory with HTTP but can't find where to config the --insecure-registry flag. The docker docs only mention where to do it on Linux. any idea?

Comment: Chen, if you are wanting to push to it as --insecure-registry flag, and are having trouble, please close/accept this ticket, and open up a new one with that specific question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker requires you to use https. What I do (I use Nexus not Artifactory) is setup a reverse proxy using nginx. Here is the doc for that - https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+a+Reverse+Proxy

Alternatively, you can set Docker to not require https (though not recommended)

Comment: So for that I need to set up a new server that will use as a reverse proxy for Docker?

Comment: @chen you could do that. What I do is I have a server that is running Docker. I then use the Nexus docker image and the docker NGINX image, all on the same server. I have had great luck with that.

Comment: Not sure how that works. How do you push local images to the Nexus(Artifactory) image through the NGINX(proxy) image?

Comment: I know about an --insecure-registry flag, do you have any idea on how to set it on windows? BTW, do I have to have hyper-v installed and create a vm in it in order to push to my production artifactory

Comment: The proxy handles the traffic. So what it will do it take the https request, and proxy it (with the security cert) and give it to the docker repository as http (or vise verse. I can't remember). You don't need to create a VM and all of that if you are not using docker-machine (using the beta version of windows) I think? I don't use Docker for Windows, but you should open up another ticket for that question.

Comment: I managed to push image with http creating a daemin.json configuration file placing it under: C:\ProgramData\docker\config\daemon.json and configure insecure-registries enrties there. I also had to set up Nginx in Artifactory to rewrite the push url. the push return a manifest invalid error but thats not for here. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear it! Enjoy Docker!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're asking how to pull, these steps worked for an enterprise artifactory where Certificate CA are not trusted outside the organization

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /etc/docker/certs.d/docker-<artifactory-resolverhost>
$ sudo cp /tmp/ca.crt /etc/docker/certs.d/docker-<artifactory-resolverhost>
$ sudo chown root:docker /etc/docker/certs.d/docker-<artifactory-resolverhost>/ca.crt
$ sudo chmod 740 /etc/docker/certs.d/docker-<artifactory-resolverhost>/ca.crt
```

Where ca.crt is the base-64 chain of CA trusted certificates and  is the resolver hostname of the repository. For ex. repo.jfrog.org if you were using the public repository. To confirm you can do a ping against "artifactory-resolverhost" to make sure is reachable from your network

Then you should be able to pull an image with your user belonging to docker group for ex.

```
docker pull docker-<artifactory-resolverhost>/<repository-name>/rhel7-tomcat:8.0.18_4
```

You can then view the downloaded image with below command

```
docker images
```